# Solving a system of differential equations in R

Tags: r, optimization, differential-equations, calculus, maximization

I have a simple flux model in R. It boils down to two differential equations that model two state variables within the model, we'll call them `A` and `B`. They are calculated as simple difference equations of four component fluxes `flux1-flux4`, 5 parameters `p1-p5`,  and a 6th parameter, `of_interest`, that can take on values between 0-1.

```
parameters<- c(p1=0.028, p2=0.3, p3=0.5, p4=0.0002, p5=0.001, of_interest=0.1) 
state     <- c(A=28, B=1.4)

model<-function(t,state,parameters){
  with(as.list(c(state,parameters)),{
  #fluxes
  flux1  = (1-of_interest) * p1*(B / (p2 + B))*p3
  flux2  = p4* A          #microbial death
  flux3  = of_interest * p1*(B / (p2 + B))*p3 
  flux4  = p5* B      

  #differential equations of component fluxes
  dAdt<- flux1 - flux2
  dBdt<- flux3 - flux4
  list(c(dAdt,dBdt))
  })
```

I would like to write a function to take the derivative of `dAdt` with respect to `of_interest`, set the derived equation to 0, then rearrange and solve for the value of `of_interest`. This will be the value of the parameter `of_interest` that maximizes the function `dAdt`.

So far I have been able to solve the model at steady state, across the possible values of `of_interest` to demonstrate there should be a maximum.

```
require(rootSolve)
range<- seq(0,1,by=0.01)
for(i in range){
of_interest=i
parameters<- c(p1=0.028, p2=0.3, p3=0.5, p4=0.0002, p5=0.001, of_interest=of_interest) 
state     <- c(A=28, B=1.4)
ST<- stode(y=y,func=model,parms=parameters,pos=T)
out<- c(out,ST$y[1])
```

Then plotting:

```
plot(out~range, pch=16,col='purple')
lines(smooth.spline(out~range,spar=0.35), lwd=3,lty=1)
```

[image]

How can I analytically solve for the value of `of_interest` that maximizes `dAdt` in R? If an analytical solution is not possible, how can I know, and how can I go about solving this numerically?

Update: I think this problem can be solved with the deSolve package in R, linked [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/deSolve/vignettes/deSolve.pdf), however I am having trouble implementing it using my particular example.

Comment: Your model seems to be a function of t, where is that variable in the function? dAdt also seems to be linear in of_interest which makes a maximum surprising. Also, what is 'out'? and where is this coming from?

Comment: @Shape `t` is a timestep, sorry for leaving this out. This is because the model iterates through time until it reaches a steady state. `out` is just a vector for saving the state variables so I can plot them through time. `out` in the `stode` code block is a vector that stores the steady state of the function at various levels of `of_interest` for the sake of plotting them. I don't know what to say that the fact there is a maximum is surprising. I've plotted the output and there is clearly a maximum.

Comment: My apologies, you're quite right, take a look at this: [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%5Bt%5D%27+%3D+a*b*c*y%5Bt%5D%2F%28d+%2B+y%5Bt%5D%29+-+e*y%5Bt%5D%3B+x%5Bt%5D%27+%3D+%281-a%29*b*c*y%5Bt%5D%2F%28d+%2B+y%5Bt%5D%29+-+f+*+x%5Bt%5D)  .It is apparently solvable (I switched to wolfram after I got worried I was going to drop something). So basically, you want the a-dependence of that final monster

Comment: @Shape this is super helpful for actually getting this to run through wolfram/mathematica, thanks! What I really want though is a way to solve this in R.

Comment: If you want a program to solve it analytically I think R is the wrong tool for the job. If you need free tools Octave would be your best bet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your equation in `B(t)` is just-about separable since you can divide out `B(t)`, from which you can get that

```
B(t) = C * exp{-p5 * t} * (p2 + B(t)) ^ {of_interest * p1 * p3}
```

This is an implicit solution for `B(t)` which we'll solve point-wise.

You can solve for `C` given your initial value of `B`. I suppose `t = 0` initially? In which case

```
C = B_0 / (p2 + B_0) ^ {of_interest * p1 * p3}
```

This also gives a somewhat nicer-looking expression for `A(t)`:

```
dA(t) / dt = B_0 / (p2 + B_0) * p1 * p3 * (1 - of_interest) *
   exp{-p5 * t} * ((p2 + B(t) / (p2 + B_0)) ^ 
   {of_interest * p1 * p3 - 1} - p4 * A(t)
```

This can be solved by integrating factor (= `exp{p4 * t}`), via numerical integration of the term involving `B(t)`. We specify the lower limit of the integral as 0 so that we never have to evaluate B outside the range `[0, t]`, which means the integrating constant is simply `A_0` and thus:

```
A(t) = (A_0 + integral_0^t { f(tau; parameters) d tau}) * exp{-p4 * t}
```

The basic gist is `B(t)` is driving everything in this system -- the approach will be: solve for the behavior of `B(t)`, then use this to figure out what's going on with `A(t)`, then maximize.

First, the "outer" parameters; we also need `nleqslv` to get `B`:

```
library(nleqslv)

t_min <- 0
t_max <- 10000
t_N <- 10

#we'll only solve the behavior of A & B over t_rng
t_rng <- seq(t_min, t_max, length.out = t_N)

#I'm calling of_interest ttheta
ttheta_min <- 0
ttheta_max <- 1
ttheta_N <- 5

tthetas <- seq(ttheta_min, ttheta_max, length.out = ttheta_N)

B_0 <- 1.4
A_0 <- 28

#No sense storing this as a vector when we'll only ever use it as a list
parameters <- list(p1 = 0.028, p2 = 0.3, p3 = 0.5, 
                   p4 = 0.0002, p5 = 0.001)
```

From here, the basic outline is:

1. Given the parameter values (in particular `ttheta`), solve for `BB` over `t_rng` via non-linear equation solving
2. Given `BB` and the parameter values, solve for `AA` over `t_rng` by numerical integration
3. Given `AA` and your expression for dAdt, plug & maximize.

derivs <- 
  sapply(tthetas, function(th){
    #append current ttheta
    params <- c(parameters, ttheta = th)

```
#declare a function we'll use to solve for B (see above)
b_slv <- function(b, t) 
  with(params, b - B_0 * ((p2 + b)/(p2 + B_0)) ^ 
         (ttheta * p1 * p3) * exp(-p5 * t))

#solving point-wise (this is pretty fast)
#  **See below for a note**
BB <- sapply(t_rng, function(t) nleqslv(B_0, function(b) b_slv(b, t))$x)

#this is f(tau; params) that I mentioned above;
#  we have to do linear interpolation since the
#  numerical integrator isn't constrained to the grid.
#  **See below for note**
a_int <- function(t){
  #approximate t to the grid (t_rng)
  #  (assumes B is monotonic, which seems to be true)
  #  (also, if t ends up negative, just assign t_rng[1])
  t_n <- max(1L, which.max(t_rng - t >= 0) - 1L)
  idx <- t_n:(t_n+1)
  ts <- t_rng[idx]

  #distance-weighted average of the local B values
  B_app <- sum((-1) ^ (0:1) * (t - ts) / diff(ts) * BB[idx])
  #finally, f(tau; params)
  with(params, (1 - ttheta) * p1 * p3 * B_0 / (p2 + B_0) *
         ((p2 + B_app)/(p2 + B_0)) ^ (ttheta * p1 * p3 - 1) *
         exp((p4 - p5) * t))
}

#a_int only works on scalars; the numeric integrator
#  requires a version that works on vectors
a_int_v <- function(t) sapply(t, a_int)

AA <- exp(-params$p4 * t_rng) * 
  sapply(t_rng, function(tt)
    #I found the subdivisions constraint binding in some cases
    #  at the default value; no trouble at 1000.
    A_0 + integrate(a_int_v, 0, tt, subdivisions = 1000L)$value)

#using the explicit version of dAdt given as flux1 - flux2
max(with(params, (1 - ttheta) * p1 * p3 * BB / (p2 + BB) - p4 * AA))})

Finally, simply run `tthetas[which.max(derivs)]` to get the maximizer.
```

## Note:

This code is not optimized for efficiency. There are a few places where there are some potential speed-ups:

- probably faster to run the equation solver recursively, as it'll converge faster with better initial guesses -- using the previous value instead of the initial value is surely better
- Will be faster to simply use Riemann sums to integrate; the tradeoff is in accuracy, but should be fine if you have a dense enough grid. One beauty of Riemann is you won't have to interpolate at all, and numerically they're simple linear algebra. I ran this with `t_N == ttheta_N == 1000L` and it ran within a few minutes.
- Probably possible to vectorize `a_int` directly instead of just `sapply`ing on it, which concomitant speed-up by more direct appeal to BLAS.
- Loads of other small stuff. Pre-compute `ttheta * p1 * p3` since it's re-used so much, etc.

I didn't bother including any of that stuff, though, because you're honestly probably better off porting this to a faster language -- Julia is my own pet favorite, but of course R speaks well with C++, C, Fortran, etc.

Comment: @colin one more thing: since we have an analytic solution (sort of) for `A(t)`, we can differentiate it with respect to `of_interest` (by also getting the derivative for `B(t)` through implicit differentiation), and maximize that numerically. Unfortunately the derivative of `A(t)` is an ungodly mess so I didn't pursue it, but I could imagine that avenue may be faster (if you find this approach to be too slow)